# How to send XML Data as Request using XML Web Service

Tags: c#

I need to send XML data to the webservice running on the host server. This webservice provides an RPC/DCE interface with a single method “XmlTransaction” that takes two parameters: a Transaction Control XML document and a Request XML document. The result is a Response XML document

The 'Transaction' method  accepts string  parameter.

Transaction(string Request);

The data reside in XML file which is test.xml.

xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"

TTC

MSG >This is a test MSG

TTC

How can i send data which is in xml file to the webservice and get the response.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Imran Khan

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET then I would start by trying to use SVCUTIL.EXE or WSDL.EXE to generate a proxy class against their service interface.